# Custom built PC takes 10 minutes to boot up

Tags: windows, boot, memory, graphics-card, motherboard

I built a music production rig about 3 years ago. The specs are:

- **Motherboard**: [MSI B350 Tomahawk Plus](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B350-TOMAHAWK-PLUS/support).
- **CPU**: [AMD Ryzen 7 3700X](https://www.amd.com/en/product/8446)
- **RAM**: [G.SKILL Ripjaws V Series](https://www.gskill.com/products/1/165/184/Ripjaws-V) 16GB (2 x 8GB) 288-Pin DDR4 SDRAM DDR4 3600
- **GPU**: [MSI GT 710 1GD3H LP](https://www.msi.com/Graphics-Card/GT-710-1GD3H-LP/Specification)
- **Storage**: [SAMSUNG 860 EVO Series](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/internal-ssd/860evo/) 2.5" 1TB SATA III V-NAND 3-bit MLC Internal Solid State Drive (SSD) MZ-76E1T0B/AM
- **OS**: Windows 10

The problem I've encountered since day one is that it takes a very long time to boot up. I get to the spinning dots for Windows and after 10 minutes of that, it's ready to go.

Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145087/discussion-on-question-by-user1786764-custom-built-pc-takes-10-minutes-to-boot-u); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.